# btsnooz.py not parsing android BT log

Tags: android, logcat, android-bluetooth, android-debug

I'm trying to follow the instructions found here:

https://inneka.com/programming/android/bluetooth-hci-snoop-log-not-generated/

and here:

https://source.android.com/devices/bluetooth/verifying_debugging#debugging-with-bug-reports

I am able to get the log, run the [python code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/bt/+/master/tools/scripts/btsnooz.py) to parse it and and it runs successfully (on my Mac) however when I open the file it looks like a bunch of gibberish. Which I'll paste below. Is there a special log viewer I need to open this up with? I might be doing something dumb, anyone run into this? Thanks!

````
‚xcƒc7f3‚xcƒc8]‚xcƒc< Ö    C‚xcƒc<˘  

‚xcƒc@l
   ˘¸Ù∂§‚xcƒcAæGG‚xcƒcFDˇˇˇÃˇÔˇˇˇ¸ÚË˛?˜èˇa˜ˇˇ¯ˇˇˇˇˇˇ¿‚xcƒcFÈ‚xcƒcJ∫ø˛œ˛€ˇ{á‚xcƒcKëV‚xcƒc‚SV‚xcƒc‰®m‚xcƒcÈ!m‚xcƒcÍL‚xcƒcÓn‚xcƒcÔç‚xcƒcÛè3‚xcƒcÙnz‚xcƒc˘>z‚xcƒc˙p ‚xcƒc˛Y Ä‚xcƒcˇY 

‚xcƒdÍ ˚‚xcƒd‹ ‚xcƒd‡ ˇˇˇˇˇ‚xcƒd ‚ ‚xcƒd
* Ô‚xcƒd
* ‚xcƒd©* Ä‚xcƒdu/ ‚xcƒdÕ/ ˚H˚H‚xcƒd®# ‚xcƒd¡# H‚xcƒdÇ ‚xcƒd£ ‚xcƒdfˇˇˇˇˇˇø=‚xcƒd!â‚xcƒd"S‚xcƒd%ù‚xcƒd)À) ‚xcƒd.) ‚xcƒd.î. Ñ‚xcƒd2k. ‚xcƒd3.E‚xcƒd=èE‚xcƒd=ˆG‚xcƒdBøG‚xcƒdC-C‚xcƒdGC‚xcƒdGp$```
````

Comment: Could you share the `BUG_REPORT.txt` file used with `btsnooz.py`?

Answer (score -1):

The comment at the top of the [btsnooz.py](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/bt/+/master/tools/scripts/btsnooz.py) script explains how to open the generated file:

> This script extracts btsnooz content from bugreports and generates a
>   valid btsnoop log file which can be viewed using standard tools like
>   Wireshark.

Wireshark can be obtained from [here](https://www.wireshark.org/).